# How to detect in Windows 8 when user changes the Location tracing to Enabled?

Tags: windows-8, geolocation, windows-runtime

I got C# Windows 8 Metro application, that is using the Geolocator class. After the geolocation was enabled during the first app start, user can  enable or disable the location tracking in app settings.

When user disables the tracking, I receive **OnStatusChanged with status == Disabled**, but when the location tracking is then enabled again using settings, I get no event at all!

So the question is how to detect when user has enabled the location tracking in settings? The only way I can think of is having some kind of periodic agent for asking about the location every couple of seconds regardless of the Geolocator status, which is still Disabled.

Comment: not a completely satisfying response, but check out this [MSDN Forums post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/3dad1050-69be-4a6e-89f1-d70cc6c3fdd7)

Comment: I ran into this today! It seems the Windows Metro/RT API's are really incomplete when you compare them to, say, Windows Phone 8... If I find a better solution I will post back!